# How can I change email link

Tags: email, redirect, outlook

How can I change for an example: a href="mailto:emailaddress.com"> So it opens a program other than outlook? If it is possible that is. Outlook is annoying and I havn't even actually made an outlook account.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of the website or the browser. Just tell Windows what your default mail client should be.

Go to Control Panel -> Default Applications and set your preferred mail client as the handler for the MAILTO protocol.